# Javascript - addEventListener button click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

After learning some Javascript, I've decided to make my first small project.
I wanted to replicate this tip calculator https://codepen.io/cphemm/pen/reNwWd

After making the HTML&CSS part of the project, I started working on the JS part, but I ran into a problem.

```js
    var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamount").value;
    var service = document.querySelector("#servive").value;
    var numberOfP = document.querySelector("#numberOfP").value;
    var calculate = document.querySelector("button");
    
    calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(billAmount <= 0 || service == 0 || numberOfP <= 0){
                    alert("Enter Valid Number");
                    return;
            }
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tip Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tipcal.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Tip Calculator</h2>
            <form action="">
               <h4>How much was your bill?</h4>
                $  <input type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount" id="billamount">
                <h4>How was your service?</h4>
                <select name="option" id="service">
                    <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
                    <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45; Outstanding</option>
                    <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45; Good</option>
                    <option value="0.15">15&#37; &#45; It was OK</option>
                    <option value="0.1">10&#37; &#45; Bad</option>
                    <option value="0.05">530&#37; &#45; Terrible</option>
                </select> 
            </form>
            <div class="sharing">
                <p>How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfP">  People
            </div>
            <div class="buttonbox">
               <button id="calculate">Calculate!</button> 
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tipcal.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html?
```

When I try to click the button, the alert message doesn't appear.

Comment: hello, have you tried to alert outside the if?

Comment: I think there is a typo in this line:

`var service = document.querySelector("#servive").value;`. "#servive" should be "#service"

Comment: @lucas.mdiniz Yes, it worked without the if.

Comment: I think if you correct the typo on the service select it will work, of not try to test the values as string And not numbers. For example, service == '0' instead of service == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some faults:

1. querySelector are made for 2 false entries: *servi**v**e* instead of `service` and *button* instead of `calculate`.
2. Getting of the values had to be in the click-function because otherwise the values are all '' (from the initial).

```js
    
    calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamount").value;
        var service = document.querySelector("#service").value;
        var numberOfP = document.querySelector("#numberOfP").value;
        var calculate = document.querySelector("#calculate");

        if (billAmount <= 0 || service == 0 || numberOfP <= 0){
          alert("Enter Valid Number");
          return;
        }
    })
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tip Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tipcal.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Tip Calculator</h2>
    <form action="">
      <h4>How much was your bill?</h4>
      $  <input type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount" id="billamount">
      <h4>How was your service?</h4>
      <select name="option" id="service">
        <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
        <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45; Outstanding</option>
        <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45; Good</option>
        <option value="0.15">15&#37; &#45; It was OK</option>
        <option value="0.1">10&#37; &#45; Bad</option>
        <option value="0.05">530&#37; &#45; Terrible</option>
      </select> 
    </form>
    <div class="sharing">
      <p>How many people are sharing the bill?</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Number of people" id="numberOfP">  People
    </div>
    <div class="buttonbox">
      <button id="calculate">Calculate!</button> 
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The query `var calculate = document.querySelector("#button");` will query for all HTML elements with an ID of "button". However, your button has an ID of "calculate", so your query selector should be `document.querySelector("button")` to find the proper element.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, you are applying querlyselecter on an element `servive` which does not exist in your html.

**Working version of your java script.**

```
    var billAmount = document.querySelector("#billamount").value;
    var service = document.querySelector("#service").value;
    var numberOfP = document.querySelector("#numberOfP").value;
    var calculate = document.querySelector("button");

    calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if(billAmount <= 0 || service == 0 || numberOfP <= 0){
                    alert("Enter Valid Number");
                    return;
            }
    })
```